# Why I can't open file?

Tags: c, file, fopen

Why it gives me that i cant open the file?

Comment: Maybe cause the file you're trying to read doesn't exist?

Comment: It does for sure, it must be something else.

Comment: Which operating system are you working on?

Comment: Linux, Jacob##################

Comment: Have you checked permissions, including ``acl`` if you're using it?

Comment: Fred, I have chmoded it to 777

Comment: and do you have ``acl`` on top of it?

Comment: And your filepath is correct?

Comment: Krister, I just write the same file name in that directory.

Comment: And if I put the name of the file in fopen, it opens.

Comment: In general, when you have an error, call `perror()` to find out what went wrong.

Comment: What does errno show as that tells you why fopen failed and what is the exact output on stderr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to wager a guess it's because you're using [fgets()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fgets/) incorrectly for this use case.

`A newline character makes fgets stop reading, but it is considered a valid character by the function and included in the string copied to str`

So you're getting a newline character with the name and trying to open that.

As this is for Linux, thus you'll most likely not have spaces in the file name, you can try this instead:

```
scanf("%s", filesIn);
```

If you do wish to use a file name with spaces, then `fgets()` from `stdin` is the way to go, but you'll have to strip that `'\n'` off.

Comment: So, what's the solution?

Comment: Thank you, you are just pure genius, wish you best in your life. Thank you thank you thank you!!!!!

Comment: @hey - Use `scanf()` as I noted, or keep using `fgets()` but strip off the newline character (`\n`).

Comment: I would wish you to go to heaven, unfortunately, there is none. But I hope everything will be good and wonderful in your life. Thank you again!

Comment: scanf() will not work if the filename contains spaces...

Comment: @digitalvision - True, my assumption here, is that the OP is going to avoid spaces since this is a Linux implementation and while spaces in Linux file names are permitted, the convention is to avoid them since they can be incompatible with legacy software in some cases. However, I will update with that note.

Answer (score 3):

The error lies in the fact that fgets() includes the newline in the read string.

Something like the following will work to remove the newline:

```
int n;

n = strlen(filesIn);
if (n > 0) filesIn[n-1] = 0;
n = strlen(filesOut);
if (n > 0) filesOut[n-1] = 0;
```